# Basic question about MVC in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the implementation of MVC in Ruby on Rails. Am I supposed to put the bulk of my code in the models, using the controllers to link them to the views? Do I use redirect_to to move between different controllers when necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your logic into the models. If needed, use redirect. But you use that often for POST answers, other use cases are not that common.